# Tangent space of the sphere of an infinite-dim Banach space

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Would someone have a reference in which it is proved that the tangent space to the sphere of an infinite-dim Banach space at x is $\{x\}^{\perp}$ please ?

Comment: What is $\{x\}^\perp$?  Additionally, how do you define the tangent space at a point on the sphere in this setting?

Comment: For Hilbert spacea it is obvious the stereographic projection still works.  For general Banach spacea you have to worry about smoothness first (the norm need not be differentiable anywhere!).

Comment: To be more explicit about Aweygan's comment - in a Hilbert space, there is an inner product that defines perpendicular. But in a Banach space, all you have is a norm. "$\perp$" is not defined there.